Most Natural Class of Machine Learning Models for Group Data
I have a dataset of performance of students in exams which looks like:
Class_ID   Class_size   Student_Number   IQ   Hours   Score   Top
1          3            3                101  10      98      1
1          3            4                99   19      80      0
1          3            6                130  3       95      0
2          5            4                93   5       50      0
2          5            5                103  9       88      0
2          5            8                112  12      99      0
2          5            1                200  10      100     1
2          5            2                90   19      78      0
3          2            5                100  12      84      0
3          2            7                102  13      88      1

and I would like to build a machine learning model trying to predict who is going to be top of the class (i.e. student with the highest Score) for any given Class_ID using IQ and Hours (number of hours studied) as features.
In other words, the input is IQ and Hours for every student (say 1 to n) in the class and the output is the probability vector (p_1, ..., p_n) where each p_i is the probability that student i have the highest score in the class.
Here is what I have tried:

the most naive approach is to use regression on Score and then to determine who will have the highest score in the class. The trouble with this approach is that this does not produce the probability of who will most likely to have the highest score in any given class.

Since this is a ranking problem, a natural class of learning models is to use the XGBRanker in XGBoost or LGBMRanker in lightgbm. Unfortunately, the output is a list of relevance score as opposed to a list of probabilities which have no natural interpretation in terms of probability.


One obvious way to get around it is to apply softmax on the relevance score in xgboost, but there is no direct meaningful probabilistic interpretation like in energy based models such as RBM's energy function. In fact, I have tried to do it and the probabilities become very extreme (most probability mass concentrates on one student for every class, giving a poor test result with high variance)

Another class of learning models is the classification model like logistic regression/ decision trees on Top. However, there are two main troubles with this approach.

First is that treating each student as a training example will not be a good approach since for example there could be two really smart (high IQ) and hardworking (high Hours) students in the same class, and if there are many such students in a lot of classes, traditional models like logistic/ tree-based models could struggle with the training.
To get around the above problem with treating individual student as a training example, we can instead treat each class as a training example. To do this, we "flatten" our dataset and do a multiclass classification on Top:
Class_ID Class_size IQ_1 IQ_2 IQ_3 IQ_4 IQ_5 Hours_1 Hours_2 Hours_3 Hours_4 Hours_5 Score_1 Score_2 Score_3 Score_4 Score_5  Top
1        3          101  99   130  NaN  NaN  10      19      3       NaN     NaN     98      80      95      NaN     NaN      3     
2        5          93   103  112  200  90   5       9       12      10      19      50      88      99      100     78       1
3        2          100  102  NaN  NaN  NaN  12      13      NaN     NaN     NaN     84      88      NaN     NaN     NaN      7

the trouble with this approach is that the number of students in each class is different,
and hence the feature matrix becomes very sparse (as the number of students in different classes can be very different)
Hence logistic model/ vanilla feedforward neural net/ tree based model doesn't seem to be natural to these kind of group data either.
So my question is, Is there any natural class of machine learning models to deal with these "group data" like the dataset I have above?
Also, in this problem, I only care about the person who ends up the top of the class (or maybe the top 3) so the ranking isn't all that important (for example knowing student 4 ranks 11th and student 8 ranks 12th does not matter all that much)
Thank you so much in advance.

Most Natural Class of Machine Learning Models for Group Data/ Race Data

I have no idea what you meant by "race data" in the title, so I removed it.

This question is similar to: XGBoost/ XGBRanker to produce probabilities instead of ranking scores. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As I've said in your other question, simply predict each individual scores, and then derive the probability they will be the top ranked student in their respective class using that. Doing this the straightforward way carries an assumption that students' scores are independent.

A suitable regression gives you the answer, especially, if you fit it in a Bayesian way via MCMC. The cool thing with MCMC samples is that you can get predict and get MCMC samples from the predictive distribution. Let's say you have 4000 MCMC samples of the predictive distribution, i.e. 4000 sets of data, in each of which you have a single predicted number for each student. You can now rank them within this predicted dataset. Then, the proportion of datasets in which they are the top ranked student (in their class, or within any other grouping that makes sense) is a prediction for the probability that they are the top ranked student.
